# Why is one of my flag pending?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I flagged [a question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50228/how-difficult-it-is-to-develope-apps-for-android-and-ios) five days ago because it seems off-topic to me. The question has been closed by a moderator few minutes after.

However my flag has not been marked as *helpful* (or *declined*, or *disputed*) in my flags summary page. It's just like the flag has not been taken into account (screenshot below).

[image]

Is a moderator can explain me?

Comment: It's all automated so I don't know. Hopefully someone from HQ can answer this for you.

Comment: Ok John, do you think it's a bug?

Comment: Could be. [Bugs happen](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/521/it-says-i-have-the-outspoken-badge-but-i-really-dont).

Comment: Ok. I'm waiting an answer from HQ someone.

Comment: I'm looking into this, it's not the first time a recommend closure flag has gone into limbo recently. Please allow a bit of time for me to chase this down.

Comment: This is a bug that affected all sites - migrating to SO and answering there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue when a mod closed a question, the "recommend close" flags were not getting cleared.

I've fixed the bugs and cleared all affected flags on all sites.

My apologies.

Comment: Thanks, my flag is not pending anymore.